# Cannot change villager profession

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I am curing zombie villagers in hopes to make a librarian.

Here's my process...

1. I start off with a lit up room for the zombie villager with just a bed in it, with no workstation nearby.
2. I find a zombie villager, making it follow me into that said room I built with just a bed.
3. I throw a splash potion of weakness and give it a golden apple
4. The zombie villager is now cured, but defaults to a tool smith - even with no workstations around or nearby his little room
5. As there is no current workstation, I put down a lecturer next to the villager in hopes to turn him into a librarian from tool smith, but nothing happens. He remains as a tool smith.

I have tried to do the above on 3 different zombie villagers. All with separate rooms. But all of them defaults to tool smiths.

I watched tutorials and you can change the villager's profession by destroying their current workstation and putting down a new one to reflect the required profession.

So this has raised the below questions -

1. Why do all the zombie villagers I cure always default to tool smiths even if there are no workstations nearby?
2. How can I change one into a librarian if they didn't have a workstation in the first place when I cured a zombie villager?

I'm playing version 1.14 on the Xbox One.

Comment: Have you tried breaking the original work station?

Comment: there was no workstation when i cured the zombie. I put the workstation (Lecturer) in after the zombie was cured,

Comment: every zombie i cure they always default to tool smiths. As much as i love tool smiths, I dont want loads. I cured another zombie, I destroyed all workstations nearby before curing it and put a lecturer in their little room. But even though theres a lecturer and no other workstations nearby, theyre still defaulting to tool smiths

Comment: Did you try to give them a bed? That has helped me before.

Comment: Villagers in bedrock are really finicky about job blocks. Once a villager claimed a job block 20 blocks below ground in my world...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to place a book and quill on the lectern as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Destroy any unclaimed professional nearby. Try to assign the cured villager to another job professional.